# Problem with mysql insert query during return to a site from a paypal payment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've stucked during debugging process of a site I build and I could use some help.

The site is a fixed price job ( fiverr like ) site. So, a "buyer" buys a job from a "seller"and pays the amount online . The money are staying temporarily in site's paypal account. So when the job is completed the seller can "withdraw" the money, and admin must transfer them to seller' s paypal acount.

Below is the message I get in browser after I have completed the "trasfer" process as admin to seller's paypal account and I return to the site using "return to merchant" paypal button.

What possibly could be wrong with this sql query?

```
CHECK_QUERY insert into `ninerr_admin_order_payment` 

(`order_status_date`,`mc_gross`,`protection_eligibility`,`address_status`,`payer_id`,`tax`,`address_street`,`payment_date`,`payment_status`,`charset`,`address_zip`,`first_name`,`address_country_code`,`address_name`,`notify_version`,`custom`,`payer_status`,`business`,`address_country`,`address_city`,`quantity`,`payer_email`,`verify_sign`,`txn_id`,`payment_type`,`payer_business_name`,`last_name`,`address_state`,`receiver_email`,`receiver_id`,`pending_reason`,`txn_type`,`item_name`,`mc_currency`,`item_number`,`residence_country`,`test_ipn`,`transaction_subject`,`handling_amount`,`payment_gross`,`shipping`,`merchant_return_link`)

VALUES ('2011:03:22','4.00','Ineligible','confirmed','7BV3JALNZYV2W','0.00','1 Main St','12:26:51 Mar 22, 2011 PDT','Pending','windows-1252','95131','Panayiotis','US','Panayiotis Kolevris's Test Store','3.1','','unverified','panayk_1299455633_per@otenet.gr','United States','San Jose','1','panayk_1299526871_biz@otenet.gr','AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AIaMVYBqWOK51ttsVWF3i1gzorhH','9E090982RT6501508','instant','Panayiotis Kolevris's Test Store','Kolevris','CA','panayk_1299455633_per@otenet.gr','DC4DA8HA7Y4U2','verify','web_accept','Withdraw','EUR','1','US','1','Withdraw','0.00','','0.00','Return to Merchant')
```

The dynamic code that produces above result is this :

```
function dataInsert($table,$dataArray){

 $fldArray=$dataArray;

    $i=0;

    $j=0;

    $sql.="insert into `".$table."` (";

    while (list($key1, $value1) = each ($fldArray)) {

        $sql.="`".$key1."`";

        $j++;

        if($j!=count($fldArray)){

        $sql.=",";

        }

        if($j==count($fldArray)){

        $sql.=") VALUES (";

        }

    }



        while (list($key1, $value1) = each ($dataArray)) {

        $sql.="'".$value1."'";

        $i++;

        if($i!=count($dataArray)){

            $sql.=",";

        }

        if($i==count($dataArray)){

        $sql.=")";

        }

    }

mysql_query($sql) or die(CHECK_QUERY.$sql);

$id=mysql_insert_id();

return $id;

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You've got error on INSERT INTO because of quote on your data:

**'Panayiotis Kolevris's Test Store'**

To fix it, try to add `mysql_escape_string(  )`:

```
while (list($key1, $value1) = each ($dataArray)) {
  $sql.= mysql_escape_string( $value1 );
  $i++;
if($i!=count($dataArray)){
  $sql.=",";
}
if($i==count($dataArray)){
  $sql.=")";
}
```

**UPDATE:**

On a second though, it seems data on `$dataArray` is already wrapped by quote ('). So, you have to escape your data before filling it into `$dataArray`.

Comment: I' m sorry silent...The dynamic code in my post was wrong...I edit and now you can see the right code. Please comment in the new one. thanks a lot

Comment: The changes are    `".$table."`  instead of ".$table." $sql.="`".$key1."`";
instead of $sql.=$key1;                                             and  $sql.="'".$value1."'";
instead of  $sql.=$value1;

Comment: OK, I replaced the sql instruction with the one you proposed but I get the same screen again. The only change is that there are not quotes in values and 'Panayiotis Kolevris's Test Store' has replaced with Panayiotis Kolevris\'s Test Store...

Comment: How do you fill `$dataArray`?

Answer (score 0):

What does the database returns? Which error?

Try to use the following instructions in you PHP and give use the output

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: I' m sorry lgor...The dynamic code in my post was wrong...I edit and now you can see the right code. Please comment in the new one. thanks a lot

Comment: My site runs on a shared host ( cpanel ) , but I still have some access in php config. As far as I can understand this feature is on, but it seems I get no error messages on it